# Mutt: Emaillist emails not be shown in inbox and still readable in some file, how to do it?

Tags: email, mutt

I get emails from mail lists such as `best-h@list.ayy.com`. I don't want them to my inbox, I want them to a new inboxes that I can only read when I select them or basically move all mails like this to a file that I can read in some way. How can I do it?

Comment: How is mail delivered to your inbox? Do you manage the SMTP server or do you know the person who does? Are you able to use mail filtering tools to handle final delivery for you?

Comment: [notmuch](http://notmuchmail.org/) with Mutt works for mail filtering and indexing; it integrates perfectly.

Comment: @D_Bye I have the server in my maintenance or better shared server and we have a support people. Mail filtering tools sounds the right thing -- I don't know anything about them. Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrative control over your SMTP server, or know those who do, you can arrange for email to be delivered by a program such as `procmail` or `maildrop` (you could also achieve this using your `~/.forward` file to send mail through a pipe to `procmail` or `maildrop`, which your mail server probably supports). Both of these tools look for a config file usually located in your home directory which contains rules specifying how a matching message should be handled. You can set up rules that look at the sender address, for example, and place matching messages in the appropriate mail box, and then using `mutt` or any other MUA you can read and dispose those messages just as you would any other.

`maildrop` supports delivering to `Maildir` style mail folders, so is a good choice if you use an IMAP server that expects that format. I haven't used `procmail` in such a long time that I don't recall whether or not it handles `Maildir`.

In addition to setting up a mail delivery agent like `maildrop` or `procmail`, you should also update your `mutt` configuration so it knows that a particular address belongs to a mailing list and that you are subscribe to it.

```
subscribe best-h@list.ayy.com
list different-list@list.ayy.com
```

The first line tells `mutt` that `best-h@list.ayy.com` is a mailing list address and that you are subscribed to the list. The second tells `mutt` that `different-list@list.ayy.com` is a mailing list to which you are not subscribed. Both will enable `mutt`'s features for handling mailing lists for any matching messages. The documentation at [mutt.org](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#using_lists) will give you a description of what these features are.

Comment: `list` command does not work in my .muttrc?!

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What error message do you receive?